# Am I missing a base case in my query helper method?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have a class, ParkingLot, and I need to write a method called, `enter()` that will check if the parking lot has any vacancies. If it does, I enter the cars license plate number and decrease the vacancy count by 1.

So far everything is working except when the parking lot becomes full, I need to adjust the `vacantSpaces` to 0.

What I have so far:

```
class ParkingLot {
  constructor(capacity, rate) {
    this.spaces = new Array(capacity).fill('vacant');
    this.rate = rate;
    this.revenue = 0;
    this.queue = new Queue();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of vacant parking spaces
   * @returns {Number}
   *  the total number of spaces where the value is "vacant".
   */

  get vacantSpaces() {
    return this.spaces.reduce(
      (sum, space, index) => sum + (space === 'vacant' ? 1 : 0),
      0
    );
  }

  /**
   * As cars enter the parking lot, the license plate number is entered and the car is parked in the first vacant space.
   * If the lot is full, the car is added to the queue to be parked when a spot is available.
   *
   * @param licensePlateNumber
   *  the license plate number of the car entering
   */

  enter(licensePlateNumber) {
    const lot = new ParkingLot(licensePlateNumber);

    if (this.spaces.length > 1) {
      lot.enter(licensePlateNumber);
      this.spaces.shift();
    }
    if (this.spaces.length < 1) {
      lot.vacantSpaces = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my test case:

```
test("is zero when lot is full", () => {
      const parkingLot = new ParkingLot(2, 1);

      parkingLot.enter("460-QRJ");
      parkingLot.enter("127-HLN");

      expect(parkingLot.vacantSpaces).toEqual(0);
    });
```

I keep getting:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: 0
Received: 1
```

Am I missing an edge case or is my current logic not set up correctly?

Comment: vacantSpaces is an accessor. You can't just set the value. But...you have bigger issues. It looks like infinite recursion on your enter() method. does it make sense that every time a car enters the parking lot you create a new parking lot?

Comment: the main thing biting you though is you don't do anything if there is 1 space left. You do something if there is more than 1 or less than 1, but you don't do anything if exactly 1 space is left.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey That makes sense. I can just use enqueue() to save the license plates and now I'm able to do `this.spaces.length >= 1`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues in your `enter` implementation:

- Don't create a new parkingLot. You need to use the current parkingLot instance (`this`) only.
- Don't call `shift` on the `this.spaces` array (Imagine all those cars that would so move to a neighboring spot!). Instead find the free spot (using `indexOf`) and write the license plate number there.
- You cannot update `this.vacantSpaces` as a property. It is a getter, not a number. There is no need to update anything, as this getter will dynamically count how many vacant spaces there are, at the moment it is called.

Here is the corrected version. I also added a `leave` method, and extended the test so the queue also gets used:

```js
class ParkingLot {
  constructor(capacity, rate) {
    this.spaces = new Array(capacity).fill('vacant');
    this.rate = rate;
    this.revenue = 0;
    // Unless you have a very efficient Queue implementation, use a native 
    // Array, which already provides Queue operations
    this.queue = []; 
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of vacant parking spaces
   * @returns {Number}
   *  the total number of spaces where the value is "vacant".
   */

  get vacantSpaces() {
    return this.spaces.reduce(
      (sum, space, index) => sum + (space === 'vacant' ? 1 : 0),
      0
    );
  }

  /**
   * As cars enter the parking lot, the license plate number is entered and the car is parked in the first vacant space.
   * If the lot is full, the car is added to the queue to be parked when a spot is available.
   *
   * @param licensePlateNumber
   *  the license plate number of the car entering
   */

  enter(licensePlateNumber) {
    // Don't create a new parkingLot. You want to use the current parkingLot instance (this)
    let space = this.spaces.indexOf('vacant');
    if (space >= 0) { // found a free spot
      this.spaces[space] = licensePlateNumber; // Overwrite 'vacant' with license place number
      // Don't shift the spaces array
    } else { // No free space
      this.queue.push(licensePlateNumber); // add to end of the queue
      // Don't write a value to this.vacantSpaces -- it already dynamically provides an updated value
    }
  }

  leave(licensePlateNumber) {
    let space = this.spaces.indexOf(licensePlateNumber);
    if (space >= 0) { // found its spot
      this.spaces[space] = 'vacant'; // Overwrite license place number with 'vacant'
      if (this.queue.length) { // There is a car waiting for a space
        this.enter(this.queue.shift()); // Attribute the first car in the queue to the new free space
      }
    }
  }
}

const parkingLot = new ParkingLot(2, 1);

parkingLot.enter("460-QRJ");
parkingLot.enter("127-HLN");

console.log("vacant spaces: ", parkingLot.vacantSpaces);

parkingLot.enter("300-BEL");

console.log("vacant spaces: ", parkingLot.vacantSpaces);

parkingLot.leave("460-QRJ");

console.log("vacant spaces: ", parkingLot.vacantSpaces);

parkingLot.leave("127-HLN");

console.log("vacant spaces: ", parkingLot.vacantSpaces);
```